# What exactly is invalidation of reference/pointer?

Tags: c++, pointers, reference, language-lawyer, invalidation

I cannot find any definition for *invalidation of pointers/references* in the Standard. I ask because I just found out that C++11 forbids copy-on-write (COW) for strings. As far as I understand, if COW was applied then `p` would be still a valid pointer and `r` a valid reference after the following commands:

```
std::string s("abc");
std::string s2(s);
char * p = &(s2[0]);
char & r = s2[0];
s2[1] = "B";
```

Just they would no longer point/refer to the first character of `s2`, but merely to the first character of `s`.

In the C++11 Standard, it is said that non-constant `std::basic_string::operator[]` may not invalidate pointers/references (and also iterators) to string elements.

Which rules say that the above shown example would actually invalidate `p` and `r` if COW was implemented?

Comment: Is that supposed to be `s2[1] = 'B';` (a `char` instead of a string literal)? What you have there shouldn't compile.

Comment: The standard only says "may be invalidated".

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is no definition for "invalidation" in the standard because the term is inherited from English. It means what it means in English: an invalidated reference/pointer is no longer valid. It cannot be used.

There are, however, places where this constraint is explicitly noted. For example, when converting a pointer lvalue to an rvalue (which happens during evaluation of an expression):

> `[conv.lval/2]` Otherwise, if the object to which the glvalue refers contains an invalid pointer value (3.7.4.2, 3.7.4.3), the behavior is implementation-defined

I can't find the wording for references right now, but it's anyway self-explanatory that you cannot use a reference to something that no longer exists.

Comment: In my example the referred to character still exists. But I can probably see your point. If `s` was destructed, then both `p` and `r` would be really invalidated even they have nothing to do with `s` by definition.

Comment: @DanielLangr You say it exists, but the implementation does not guarantee it to you. That's what invalidation means. Same as any other "may be, may not be" scenario in C++. You are advised to code to contract rather than to chance. It is agreed that there may be some situations where you can actually know with great certainty that an invalidated object will in reality still exist. However, such situations are generally contrived and do not guide the general case.

Comment: [conv.lval] means https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/basic.compound#def:invalid_pointer_value, exact definition, not «the term ... inherited from English»

Answer (score 0):

For example:

```
std::string * p_s(new ::std::string("abc"));
std::string s2(*p_s); // shares buffer with p_s
char const & ch1(static_cast<::std::string const &>(*p_s)[0]);
char const & ch2(static_cast<::std::string const &>(s2)[0]); // same as ch1
// CoW, ch2 becomes invalid, but is backed by p_s buffer
char & ch(static_cast<::std::string &>(s2)[0]); // backed by new buffer
// both ch1 and ch2 become invalid
delete p_s;
```